# swift: Crash on physicsBody from texture

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I made a node called bone which is made from a bone image. This node works perfectly. After I render it, I try to create a `SKPhysicsBody` for it, but that line causes a crash. I can't figure out whats the problem.

Here, I declare the SKSpriteNode on top of the class

`let bone = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bone")`

Here, I set it up. The last line is the one that causes the crash.

```
bone.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
bone.position.x = CGFloat(arc4random() % (UInt32(self.view.frame.size.width)) + 1)
bone.position.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + bone.size.height/2

self.addChild(bone)

let boneBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: self.view.textureFromNode(bone), size: bone.size)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what crash? log? callstack?

Comment: It sends me to appDelegate and says: `+[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:size:]: unrecognized selector sent to class`


Also, the compiler displays message `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

Comment: sounds like you are not running this code on ios 8 device/simulator

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not thinking of such trivial problem. I've been developing some time on my iOS 7 device and had no problems. I forgot this is iOS 8 exclusive function. Thank you very much. Please write this as an answer so other folks can see it and you can gain credit. Thanks again.